# DolphinDB pivot table

Tags: pivot, dolphindb

I have a table something looking like this:

```
id CompanyName ProductID productName
-- ----------- --------- -----------
1  c1          1         p1         
2  c1          2         p2         
3  c2          2         p2         
4  c2          3         p3         
5  c3          3         p3         
6  c4          3         p3         
7  c5          4         p4         
8  c6          4         p4         
9  c6          5         p5
```

Is it possible to run a DolphinDB query to get output like this:

```
companyName p1  p2  p3  p4  p5
------------------------------
c1          1   1   0   0   0
c2          0   1   1   0   0
c3          0   0   1   0   0
c4          0   0   1   0   0
c5          0   0   0   1   0
c6          0   0   0   1   1
```

The value in the above table is the number of each product in each company.I get it by the query:

```
select count(*) from t group by companyName,productName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t1=select count(ProductID) from t pivot by CompanyName, productName
nullFill!(t1,0)
```

Comment: Explanation please

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Comment: pivot by is a unique feature in DolphinDB, and an extension to the standard SQL. It rearranges a column of a table on two dimensions. count(ProductID) can get the number of each product in each compan. nullFill!(t,0)  will replace all NULLs in a table t